# ubuntu 20.04 not connecting to network after sudden power off

Tags: networking, shutdown, soundcard

i have a relatively old desktop system running ubuntu 20.04

where i live there are many sudden poweroffs, after one of these poweroffs system sound got messed up and is not giving sound to my speakers anymore.
that i can live with right now

but USB tethering also doesn't work

can anyone workup a solution with me here?

usb ports works, i have exchanged data with it and my mouse and keyboard is connected via usb

thank you